# About lazyness of Option's or_else() method

Tags: rust

According to [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.or), `or_else` is lazily evaluated. I tried this, but it's not working.

I understand that `get_mut` is not needed here; it's just for demonstration.

```rs
    let mut map = HashMap::from([("key", "value")]);
    let key = "KeY";

    // this is fine
    if map.get_mut(key).is_some()
        || map.get_mut(key.to_uppercase().as_str()).is_some()
        || map.get_mut(key.to_lowercase().as_str()).is_some()
    {
        println!("is some");
    }

    // error: cannot borrow `map` as mutable more than once
    if map
        .get_mut(key)
        .or_else(|| map.get_mut(key.to_uppercase().as_str()))
        .or_else(|| map.get_mut(key.to_lowercase().as_str()))
        .is_some()
    {
        println!("is some");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fails because the return value of `get_mut` extends the mutable borrow of `map`.  When you try to invoke `or_else`, `map` must be borrowed mutably (again) to create the closure.  It's a bit obfuscated by the `get_mut` call and the closure, but this is effectively what you're trying to do:

```
struct Foo;

impl Foo {
    pub fn bar(&mut self, _: &mut Foo) {}
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo;
    foo.bar(&mut foo);
}
```

This breaks Rust's aliasing rule that a value may be mutated through at most one name at a given time.  In your case, you're invoking `Option::or_else`, which has this signature:

```
pub fn or_else<F>(self, f: F) -> Option<T>
where ...
```

In your code, both `self` and `f` are trying to borrow `map` mutably.
Unfortunately, some of the `Option` utilities don't work very well in these kinds of cases.  Conceptually, we know that this is safe because `f` doesn't even get invoked unless `self` is `None`, in which case nothing is borrowed, but the compiler doesn't know this.

The first code sample you give is exactly how I would rewrite it.  The `||` boolean operator short-circuits, so this is lazily-evaluated in the same way that the second code sample would be, were it allowed.